# My printer does not execute any command over USB

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code, firmware, pronterface, tevo-tornado

I have a Tevo Tornado, it seemingly connects fine, it is recognised by the software and it turns on.
Any command I send over USB is not executed, as if it's not registering them.
I tried on Cura and Pronterface and the printer is unresponsive.
In particular in Pronterface it displays:

```
echo:busy: processing
```

but nothing is executed.

---

*This is part of a broader set of problems I am trying to diagnose on the printer; most of them are explained in [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16790/my-3d-printer-checks-axes-home-during-print-often-wrecking-the-print).
I am trying to section off the individual problems and fix, bit by bit, the whole printer.*

Comment: What command(s) did you send that got that response?  Valid gcode?

Comment: Anything from homing to a G-Code file to print.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cable?

Comment: Yes. FYI this is part of a broader set of problems I'm trying to diagnose on the printer.
If you are curious you can find most of them explained in this question:
https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16790/my-3d-printer-checks-axes-home-during-print-often-wrecking-the-print
I'm trying to section off the individual problems and fix, bit by bit, the whole printer.